# OpenVPN server certificate configuration instructions for DD-WRT router do not match user interface

Tags: vpn, dd-wrt, openvpn, certificate, buffalo-router

I'm setting up the OpenVPN server daemon on a Buffalo N600 router which came stock with DD-WRT v.24 SP2.

I'm following the instructions at [VPN (The Easy Way) V24+](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/VPN_%28the_easy_way%29_v24+) to set up the server side of things and then set up an OpenVPN client (running on Windows).  The instructions start out with:

> As of DD-WRT v.24 SP1, it is now possible to set up DD-WRT as an OpenVPN appliance using only the web-based GUI. It is no longer necessary to issue shell commands, or to echo quoted certificates and config files using a shell script.

Sounds good.  Here's a screenshot of the router's OpenVPN server configuration screen:

Given the statement about GUI support, I left "Config via" set as "GUI".

[image: Buffalo N600 DD-WRT OpenVPN server configuration section]

I followed the "Creating Certificates Using Easy RSA in Windows" section and created my certs with no problems.  The documentation then talks about pasting the certs I just created into the relevant fields on the router's config screen:

[image: Certificate Mappings]

The first row says that into the "Public Server Cert (CA Cert)" field I should insert the contents of the "ca.crt" file.  But there is a "Public Server Cert" field and a "CA Cert" field.  And the 3rd row says that into the "Public Server Cert" field I should insert the contents of the "server.crt" file.

The field mappings don't match and are ambiguous.  What goes where?  Should I really be in GUI mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Typically**, Using Easy RSA in Windows, these would be the files:

`Public Server Cert (CA Cert)` will be named `ca.crt`
This is the root CA of your personal PKI.

`Public Server Cert` will be named `server.crt` This is your server X509 certificate. You are free to name this file as you see fit.

`Private server key` will be named `server.key` This is your server private key. You are free to name this file as you see fit.

`dh.pem` will be named `dhxxxx.pem` or just `dh.pem`
This is the Diffie Hellman key - `xxxx` can represent the number of bits used when creating the file eg: 2048

`TLS Auth` will be named `ta.key` This is the TLS authorization key or HMAC key. This is **highly** recommended that you use.

`GUI mode` looks suitable for this task.